# What will be SQL syntax for Show the artists with number of albums they have in descending order

Tags: mysql

Two tables Album (AlbumId, Title, ArtistID) and Artist (ArtistId and Name) are given.

```
SELECT ARTISTID FROM ALBUMS GROUP BY ARTISTID HAVING COUNT(ARTISTID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that `HAVING COUNT` is used to:

> The MySQL HAVING clause is used in combination with the GROUP BY
> clause to restrict the groups of returned rows to only those whose the
> condition is TRUE.
> Check to learn about `HAVING COUNT` clause: https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/having.php

I do not know your table description, but something like this would help:

```
CREATE TABLE Album (
  AlbumId int(9),
  Title varchar(100),
  ArtistID int(9) );

INSERT INTO Album  VALUES (1,'Test1',2),
                          (2,'Test2',2),
                          (3,'Test4',1),
                          (4,'Test2',3);

CREATE TABLE Artist (
  ArtistId int(9),
  Name varchar(50) );
                         
INSERT INTO Artist  VALUES (1,'John'),
                           (2,'Anna'),
                           (3,'Enzo');



select   Artist.Name,
         Artist.ArtistId,
         count(Title) as number_of_albums
from Artist
inner join Album on Artist.ArtistId=Album.ArtistId   
group by  Artist.Name,Artist.ArtistId;
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pB6b5xrgPKCivFWcpQHsyE/27

Comment: What will be the SQl command for Find the name of the tracks that occur most frequently in playlist TV Shows and
playlist 90’s music. I have three different tables track(TrackId, Name,AlbumId etc.), Playlist (PlaylistId, Name) and Playlisttrack(PlaylistId,TrackId).

Comment: @AllexSmith  I can't be sure without data templates and expected results, but you can use count(*) and filter the data after group by with the having count clause, you can use MAX(), but max return only the biggest value

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT COUNT(*) as album_count,Album.Title, Artist.ArtistId, Artist.Name 
FROM Album 
LEFT JOIN Artist ON Album.ArtistID = Artist.ArtistId 
GROUP BY Artist.ArtistId 
ORDER BY album_count DESC
```

[image]